# React - How to change child state based on click event to parent

Tags: reactjs

I have set up a sidebar like this

```
<SideBar>
    <SideBarItem/>
    <SideBarItem selected/>
    <SideBarItem/>
</SideBar>
```

The selection determines a border color. Now when I click the sidebar, i want the border color to change accordingly. Here is my attempt

```
require('./SideBar.scss');
export class SideBar extends React.Component {
    setSelection(e) {
        // Set the selection border
        console.log(e);
        this.props.children.forEach(child => {
            console.log(child)
            if (child == e.target) { // This doesn't work
                child.select();
            } else {
                child.deSelect();
            }
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.setSelection.bind(this)} className="SideBar">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
};

require('./SideBar.scss');
export class SideBarItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        if (props.selected) {
            this.state = {selected: true, style: {
                boxShadow: '4px 0 0 #10956D'
            }};
        } else {
            this.state = {selected: false, style: {}};
        }
    }
    select() {
        this.setState({selected: true, style: '4px 0 0 #10956D'});
    }
    deSelect() {
        this.setState({selected: false, style: ''});
    }
    render() {
        return (<div onClick={this.props.onClick} style={this.state.style} className="SideBarItem">
            {this.props.children}
        </div>);
    }
};
```

As you can see the idea is to have a click handler for the SideBar which iterates through the children and compares it to the event. I couldn't find a way to check if the event target matches a child.

Comment: why are you adding an onClick handler in parent which invokes methods on children instead of adding onClick handler in children?

Comment: Because i need to call deSelect on the other children @pwolaq , if I instead add the handler to each children how do I deselect the previously selected item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve desired behavior by forcing `SideBar` to attach `onClick` handlers to every child. And passing index of the clicked children as argument - so later you can uniquely identify it.

Something like this in `SideBar.render` should do the trick:

```
var childIndex = -1;
var modifiedChildren = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => 
{
    childIndex++;
    return React.cloneElement(
        child,
        {onClick: () => this.setSelection(childIndex)},
        child.props.children);
})

return <div className="SideBar">{modifiedChildren}</div>
```